# SonarQube API Issue search is only returning 100 results

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.1, sonarqube-web

Utilizing SonarQube 5.1, I have been attempting to utilize the API search feature to gather all of the issues pertaining to my current project to display on a radiator.    On the Web interface, SonarQube indicates there are 71 major issues and 161 minor issues.

Using this search string
https://sonarqube.url.com/api/issues/search?projectKeys=myproject'skey

I get back a response with exactly 100 results.   When I process those results for only OPEN items, I get back a total of 55 issues.   36 major, 19 minor.

This is being achieved through a Powershell script that authenticates to the SonarQube server and passes in the query, then deserializes the response into an array I can process. (Counting major/minor issues)

With the background out of the way, the meat of my question is:  Does anyone know why the responses I am receiving are locked at 100?   In my research I saw others indicating a response to an issue search would be capped at 500 due to an outstanding bug.     However the expected number of issues I am looking for is far below that number.     The API's instructions indicate that it would return the first 10,000 issues.      Is there a server side setting that restricts the output it will return to a search query?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 5):

The [web service docs](https://next.sonarqube.com/sonarqube/web_api/api/issues/search) show that 100 is the default value of the `ps` parameter. You can set the value higher, but it will still max out.

You might have noticed a `"paging"` element in the JSON response. You can use it to calculate how many pages of results there are and loop through them using the `p` parameter to specify page number.

Comment: But isn't there any way to get records more than 10,000?